# Using Linq to filter by List<ListItem>

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to extend my linq query with additional search criteria to filter the data by sending also a `List<Listitem>` to the function for processing. The List can contain 1 or more items and the objective is to retreive all items which match any criteria. 
Since i am sending several search criteria to the function the goal is to make a more accurate filter result the more information i am sending to the filter. If one or several criterias are empty then the filter will get less accurate results. 
Exception is raised every time i execute following code, and I cant figure out how to solve the using statement to include the `List<ListItem>`. Appreciate all the help in advance!

Exception: `Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

```
using (var db = new DL.ENTS())
{
    List<DL.PRODUCTS> products = 
    (from a in db.PRODUCTS
      where (description == null || description == "" || 
            a.DESCRIPTION.Contains(description)) &&
            (active == null || active == "" || a.ACTIVE.Equals(active, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) &&
            (mID == null || mID == "" || a.MEDIA_ID == mID) &&
            (mID == null || objTypes.Any(s => s.Value == a.OBJECTS)) //Exception here!
      select a).ToList<DL.PRODUCTS>();

    return products;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass collection of primitive values to expression:

```
using (var db = new DL.ENTS())
{
    var values = objTypes.Select(s => s.Value).ToArray();

    List<DL.PRODUCTS> products = 
        (from a in db.PRODUCTS
         where (description == null || description == "" || a.DESCRIPTION.Contains(description)) &&
               (active == null || active == "" || a.ACTIVE.Equals(active, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) &&
               (mID == null || mID == "" || a.MEDIA_ID == mID) &&
               (mID == null || values.Contains(a.OBJECTS)) 
         select a).ToList<DL.PRODUCTS>();

    return products;
}
```

That will generate SQL IN clause.

---

Note - you can use lambda syntax to compose query by adding filters based on some conditions:

```
 var products = db.PRODUCTS;

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
     products = products.Where(p => p.DESCRIPTION.Contains(description));

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(active))
     products = products.Where(p => p.ACTIVE.Equals(active, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mID))
     products = products.Where(p => p.MEDIA_ID == mID);

 if (mID != null)
     products = products.Where(p => values.Contains(p.OBJECTS));

 return products.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq isn't able to convert the predicate on `ListItem` to something useful to Sql.

I would suggest that you pre-project the values of the `ListItems` into a simple `List<string>` before using this with Contains (which is converted to IN)

```
var listValues = objTypes.Select(_ => _.Value).ToList();
   List<DL.PRODUCTS> products = ...
   listValues.Contains(a.OBJECTS))
```